# How vnext web applications are self hostable?

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm new to .net and so to vnext. Earlier we used IIS to host a MVC application, still web api were self hostable. But now in vnext we have got web applications which are also self hostable. I actually wanted to know how vnext web application can be self hosted and what makes it self hostable? What are the changes in architecture and request life cycle.

Answer (score -1):

vNext uses OWIN under the covers. As long as a server implements the OWIN interfaces you should be able to run your vNext middleware.

You can currently use nowin to host your OWIN app inside your own appdomain
https://github.com/Bobris/Nowin

For an example, look at the helloworldweb sample in
https://github.com/desdesdes/HelloWorldVNext

Comment: BTW ASP.NET 5 (formerly known as ASP.NET vNext) does *not* use OWIN. There are, however, compatibility layers to enabled OWIN middleware to be used in ASP.NET 5, and one could potentially write a layer to enable ASP.NET 5 middleware on an OWIN server.